# Search for specific part of a line

Tags: sed, grep, search

I want to have this script which will store users in the format:`<$AccountName> <$DOB> <$Username><$Password> <$Email>` on a file called Register.txt. I want to have it search the file to see if the username already exists in Register.txt before adding the account to the file. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the usernames, then search:

```
newuser="waltinator"
cut "-d " -f3 Register.txt | \
  grep -F -w "$newuser" | \
  wc -l
```

Read `man cut grep wc`.